# Perl: pair elements in two list

Tags: perl

I have two lists:

```
my @prefixes = ["abc", "def", "ghi", "jklmn"];
my @strings = ["abc123", "def456", "jklmnopqrst"];
```

I need to find the correct prefix for each string so that "abc123" belongs to "abc" and "def456" belongs to "def" and "jklmnopqrst" belongs to "jklmn".
All strings has a prefix in @prefixes but not all prefix has a matching string (see "ghi").

I have this code:

```
use List::Util qw(first);
...
foreach my $str (@strings) {
    my $prefix = first { $_ eq substr($str, 0, length($_)) } @prefixes;
    print "$prefix\n";
    # do something with $str and $prefix together
}
```

But it's not working, I'm getting `Use of uninitialized value $prefix in concatenation (.) or string`

What's wrong?

**UPDATE**: So it was an easy fix. I should have initialized my lists using () and not []. To not to close this yet, how would you get rid of the `foreach` statement?

Comment: Ok, I'm dumb. I should have initialized my arrays with () instead of [].

Comment: With `map` -- but then you don't have as much flexibility to process inside as you do with `foreach`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a regex pattern from the prefixes and use that to construct a hash:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use YAML::XS;

my @prefixes = qw[abc def ghi jklmn];
my @strings  = qw[abc123 def456 jklmnopqrst];

my ($prefix_re) = map qr/$_/, sprintf(
    '^(?<prefix>%s)',
    join '|', sort { length $b <=> length $a } @prefixes
);

print "$prefix_re\n";

my %matches = map { $_ =~ $prefix_re; ($+{prefix}, $_) } @strings;

print Dump \%matches;
```

Output:

```
abc: abc123
def: def456
jklmn: jklmnopqrst
```

If multiple strings can match a prefix, you can map prefixes to lists of matched strings:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use YAML::XS;

my @prefixes = qw[abc def ghi jklmn];
my @strings  = qw[abc123 def456 def789 jklmnopqrst];

my ($prefix_re) = map qr/$_/, sprintf(
    '^(?<prefix>%s)',
    join '|', sort { length $b <=> length $a } @prefixes
);

print "$prefix_re\n";

my %matches;

for my $str ( @strings ) {
    next unless $str =~ $prefix_re;
    push @{ $matches{ $+{prefix} }}, $str;
}

print Dump \%matches;
```

Output:

```
---
abc:
- abc123
def:
- def456
- def789
jklmn:
- jklmnopqrst
```

Comment: That's another nice solution! Thank you a lot!

Comment: Glad it helped. Keep in mind that you might be better off in terms of memory footprint and performance if you just match, process, and move on instead of storing matches.

Answer (score 2):

In place of the `foreach` you could use `map`, however, the code becomes considerably less readable.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util qw/ first /;

my @prefixes = ("abc", "def", "ghi", "jklmn");
my @strings = ("abc123", "def456", "jklmnopqrst");

# foreach my $str ( @strings ) {
#   my $prefix = first { $_ eq substr( $str, 0, length( $_ )) } @prefixes;
#   print $prefix, "\n";
# }

my @found  = map { my $str = $_; first { $_ eq substr( $str, 0, length( $_ ))} @prefixes } @strings;

print join("\n", @found), "\n";
```